# Troubleshooting and error logs etc. for external harddrive mount and unmounting problems

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mount

More than one harddrive that I have tried connecting to my MacBook Pro A1990 running macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) have displayed this kind of behaviour:

After being mounted for a while, the partitions get unmounted, then mount back, and then a while later they get unmounted again, and the cycle repeats.
The data is all intact for now, as long as the partitions are mounted.

I have tried connecting to different USB-C ports on my computer, and the behaviour continues to be shown.

The harddrives are relatively new. They are all of the same model:
https://www.amazon.sg/gp/product/B076MPMZDV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

All of them are formatted as such:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *6.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS B14P1                   499.9 GB   disk4s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS B14P2                   499.9 GB   disk4s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS B14P3                   499.9 GB   disk4s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS B14P4                   499.9 GB   disk4s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS B14P5                   499.9 GB   disk4s6
   7:                  Apple_HFS B14P6                   499.9 GB   disk4s7
   8:                  Apple_HFS B14P7                   499.9 GB   disk4s8
   9:                  Apple_HFS B14P8                   499.9 GB   disk4s9
  10:                  Apple_HFS B14P9                   499.9 GB   disk4s10
  11:                  Apple_HFS B14P10                  499.9 GB   disk4s11
  12:                  Apple_HFS B14P11                  499.9 GB   disk4s12
  13:                  Apple_HFS B14P12                  500.8 GB   disk4s13
```

I haven't tried a different model bec I do not have access to different kind of harddrive at the moment.

This sort of behaviour is new. It hasn't happened at all, until recently. And for one of the harddrive, it did not happen at all for a few months before it all started.

Is there a way I can find out more why this thing is happening? eg. An error log, or how I can dump more info on the Terminal for troubleshooting whenever this happens?

(Of course, I am also open to direct suggestions on what could be the reason and how to solve it.)

Comment: You don’t mention how it is formatted. Run DiskUtility and be more specific.

Comment: @IconDaemon sorry I didn't think that was an important piece of info.. I edited the question to provide that already.

Comment: macOS Ventura (macOS 13) is in beta and has not been released to the 'public'. As a beta release, there will be things which are definitely not working correctly. Perhaps your problems are related to this beta release.

Comment: @IconDaemon really sorry I did not notice the typo until now. it's macOS10.13.6 not 13.10.6. I have been using 10.13.6 and this brand of harddrive for a few years now. but I nv had the problem stated in the question until 1-2 weeks back. I think being able to find error logs etc. will be v useful, if you could advise..